# XML Unmarshalling Error

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm unable to figure the below unmarshalling error that I'm receiving. Please help. I have reviewed passed posts and I don't know whats going on.

unexpected element (uri:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", local:"Envelope")

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tt="http://sample.examples">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <tt:VersionResponse>
     <tt:SchemaVersionDeclared>1.0.0.1</tt:SchemaVersionDeclared>
  </tt:VersionResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

static public String getVersionFromWSResponseFromJAXB(XMLStreamReader xsr) {
    String versionDataAsXML = badData;

    try {           

        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(SchemaVersion.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

        CommonMovementRequirementSchemaVersion schemaVersionDeclared = (SchemaVersion) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr);

        // Check for empty result
        if (!badData.equalsIgnoreCase(schemaVersionDeclared.getSchemaVersionDeclared())) {
            versionDataAsXML =   schemaVersionDeclared.getSchemaVersionDeclared();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return versionDataAsXML;
}


package org.examples.tools;
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import org.examples.tools.WebServiceTools;



public class TestGetVersionFromWSResponseFromJAXB {

public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception { 

    XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
    StreamSource xml = new StreamSource("C:/examples/VersionResponse.xml");
    XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(xml);

    String result = WebServiceTools.getVersionFromWSResponseFromJAXB(xsr); 
    // Treat result

   System.out.print(result);

}
}

package org.examples.tools;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "SchemaVersion", propOrder = {
"schemaVersionDeclared"
})
public class SchemaVersion {

@XmlElement(name = "SchemaVersionDeclared", required = true, defaultValue = "1.0.0.0")
protected String schemaVersionDeclared;

public void setSchemaVersionDeclared(String value) {
    this.schemaVersionDeclared = value;
}

}
```

Comment: Hard to say without seeing SchemaVersion.class, the exception should tell you what the expected elements were. Most likely you are using wrong jaxb context to your unmarshalling or you don't have namespaces declared on your beans.

Comment: added SchemaVersion Class

Answer (score 1):

Your context has nothing to do with the xml you are parssing:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(SchemaVersion.class);

SchemaVersion {
@XmlElement(name = "SchemaVersionDeclared", required = true, defaultValue = "1.0.0.0")
protected String schemaVersionDeclared;
```

The expected xml is then:

```
<SchemaVersion>
    <SchemaVersionDeclared>xxx</SchemaVersionDeclared>
</SchemaVersion>
```

Comment: Can you explain further?

Comment: Are you saying I need to "Get" the SchemaVersion instance?

Comment: I am sayin that your code is trying to read xml like <SchemaVersionDeclared>xxx</SchemaVersionDeclared> not the one you gave as the example

Comment: made XML to match <SchemaVersionDeclared>xxx</SchemaVersionDeclared> and still receiving this error [com.sun.istack.internal.SAXParseException2; systemId: file:///C:/examples/VersionResponse.xml; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 58; unexpected element (uri:"", local:"SchemaVersionDeclared"). Expected elements are (none)]

Comment: add @XMLRoot on top of your SchemaVersion class. And the xml has to have SchemaVersion as first tag. Nevertheless are you trying to guess the right xml to use with your code or fix the code to read the given xml.

Comment: guess the correct code that tests the method to unmarshall the XML.

Comment: I should be able to JAXB to parse the body of the XML Response. This is a sample of a SOAP response for a mock service that I created.

Comment: tried adding @XMLRootElement(name = SchemaVersion). still getting nexpected element (uri:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", local:"Envelope").